# How to work on a project with limited access?

Tags: methodology

It's nice to have a complete project at your disposal to see how an application works when it's modified.

That's in an ideal situation. Now, say you have ftp access to a web site root with all the source files, you're unfamiliar with the site structure, you have no direct access to the database (so you can only guess the structure...) and the site just happens to be live.

How do you go about adding some features in a context like this?

P.S: Title is a reference to so-called keyhole surgery.

Comment: With or without the owner's knowledge?

Comment: With the owner's knowledge ;)

Comment: 1) Upload a file that creates a db dump 2) download all the source-code and the dump 3) Treat it like any other project

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Sensible answer. Doing out a dump and downloading all the source-code should be straightforward and it'd be possible to reconstitute a full project. P.S: If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look through the source files and see if you can find any connection information for the database.

Comment: That's an idea. Do you think that with this information it would be possible to see the table structure? A minimalistic viewer script probably exists for PHP but I don't know if such a thing exists for ASP.NET/C#.

Comment: If you find the connection information for the db, you can use relational db software specific to your apps db flavor to look at the db

Comment: Ok. Can this be done remotely? I know that a MySQL database requires port 3306 to be open (an ASP site probably use MS SQL Server...). Obviously most hosts block that.

Comment: @CodeInChaos' suggestion of simply dumping the database is a good one. I'll see if I can find a basic dumping script.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really into dissecting the webpage structure, you can go as far as writing or using a webpage parser and compare the site across its entire set of links. From there, you can pretty much make out the templates, content nodes, etc. Hope it helps.